# Concurrency on PostgreSQL Database with python subprocesses

Tags: python, postgresql, subprocess, multiprocessing

I use python multiprocessing processes to establish multiple connections to a postgreSQL database via psycopg.

Every process establishes a connection, creates a cursor, fetches an object from a `mp.Queue` and does some work on the database. If everything works fine, the changes are commited and the connection is closed.

If one of the processes however creates an error (e.g. an ADD COLUMN request fails, because the COLUMN is already present), all the processes seem to stop working.

```
import psycopg2
import multiprocessing as mp
import Queue

def connect():
    C = psycopg2.connect(host = "myhost", user = "myuser", password = "supersafe", port = 62013, database = "db")
    cur = C.cursor()
    return C,cur

def commit_and_close(C,cur):
    C.commit()
    cur.close()
    C.close()

def commit(C):
    C.commit()

def sub(queue):
    C,cur = connect()
    while not queue.empty():
        work_element = queue.get(timeout=1)
        #do something with the work element, that might produce an SQL error
    commit_and_close(C,cur)       
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    job_queue = mp.Queue()
    #Fill Job_queue
    print 'Run'
    for i in range(20):
        p=mp.Process(target=sub, args=(job_queue))
        p.start()
```

I can see, that processes are still alive (because the job_queue is still full), but no Network traffic / SQL actions are happening. Is it possible, that an SQL error blocks communication from other subprocesses? How can I prevent that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As chance would have it, I was doing something similar today.

It shouldn't be that the state of one connection can affect a different one, so I don't think we should start there.

There is clearly a race condition in your queue handling. You check if the queue is empty and then try to get a statement to execute. With multiple readers one of the others could empty the queue leaving the others all blocking on their `queue.get`. If the queue is empty when they all lock up then I would suspect this.

You also never `join` your processes back when they complete. I'm not sure what effect that would have in the larger picture, but it's probably good practice to clean up.

The other thing that might be happening is that your error-ing process is not rolling back properly. That might leave other transactions waiting to see if it completes or rolls back. They can wait for quite a long time by default but you can [configure it](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LOCK-TIMEOUT).

To see what is happening, fire up psql and check out two useful system views `pg_stat_activity` and `pg_locks`. That should show where the cause lies.

Comment: The timeout statement in the `que.get()`should lead to an error if no element is available in 1 second, so this is no real race condition. I don't want to join my processes, as I want to be able to check the conditions of my programm from my main processes (e.g. I can check queue.empty() etc.). That leaves your last point as a possible cause. I am pretty sure, that the behaviour is somehow SQL related, as I always see an SQL error in one of the processes when the others are being locked.

Comment: I fired up ´pg_stat_activity´ and can see an idle process with ´COMMIT´ query. Nevertheless it goes away some seconds later.

Comment: They are waiting for another transaction to either commit or rollback. Until then PostgreSQL can't decide if these transactions will succeed or not. Check that you are rolling back the failing transaction promptly.